# hibernate define class from multiple columns in multiple tables

Tags: sql, hibernate, annotations, hql, pojo

i have a class with some datafields:

```
class Call{
roomId
roomDisplay
roomLocation
typeId
name
staffAidId
}
```

now i would like to map this using hibernate annotations in java
but the original sql query that i used was something like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.roomId, 
    r.display, 
    r.location, 
    c.typeId, 
    c.staffAidId, 
    s.firstname,
  s.lastname
FROM callalert c 
JOIN staffmember s  
LEFT JOIN roomGroup g ON g.groupId = s.roomGroupId 
LEFT JOIN room r ON r.roomId = g.roomId
WHERE s.staffId = 4444 AND c.roomId = g.roomId
```

is there a way to map this
in other words:
is there a way to map columns from different tables to 1 custom class?
the class is no direct representation of 1 table
and from all the tables that are involved, not all columns are used

### edit

I tried the view solution:

created a view with the above query
then I try to generate the hibernate classes using Netbeans
and I generates 2 classes:
the class Calls and an Embeddable class CallId

after searching the Internet this happens because hibernate needs a primary key so it creates one himself

how can I make sure only 1 class gets generated?
how do I give a view a primary key (a good primary key would be 1 of the primary keys of the underlying tables). how do i set this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that if you create a database view for that query. It would work, but it has the downside that you can't auto-generate the ddl schema from the database models.

Check out this [article](http://en.newinstance.it/2005/07/11/hibernate-and-database-views/)

Comment: With the aggravating that the class could not be used to update code in the database, unless the view itself is updatable.

Comment: I tried it but it generates 2 classes: check the first post after "edit"